# ERRORLEVEL conditions

Tags: batch-file, conditional-statements, errorlevel

Should this logic not send 0 and 1 error levels to the 'mailerror' subroutine and simply exit if they are 0 or 1 errors?

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (   
    SET BODY="exit error code from Backup of RAD file = %ERRORLEVEL%."
    goto mailerror
    )
 ) ELSE (
 EXIT
 )
```

Comment: Are you looking for `If %ErrorLevel% Gtr 1`? (`If ErrorLevel 2`). BTW, an errorlevel of `0` is not what I'd term an error, it is usually a success. `If Not ErrorLevel 1` will usually be used to identify an `ErrorLevel` of `0` whereras `If ErrorLevel 1` is usually used to determine anything which wasnt successful, _i.e. an error_.

Comment: No. The `else` clause refers to the outer `if` condition only. So an `%ErrorLevel%` of `0` results in `exit`, but **an `%ErrorLevel%` of `1` results in no action**! All other values, including negative ones, result in a jump to the routine `:mailerror`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need all those parenthesis. Also, you are currently testing for errorlevel `0` and then `1`, but your `else` is in the wrong place and therefore `errorlevel 1` clause will do nothing (not exit):

This would test and action exit on both `errorlevel 0` and then `errorlevel 1`

```
@echo off
if %errorlevel% neq 0 if %errorlevel% neq 1 (
set BODY="exit error code from Backup of RAD file = %errorlevel%."
echo %body%
goto mailerror
)
exit
:mailerror
echo %BODY%
echo do something else..
```

But seeing as you want to do anything other than errorlevel `0` and `1` you could simply do set if `%errorlevel%` greater than `1` (in otherwords not `0` or `1`):

```
@echo off
if %errorlevel% GTR 1 (
set BODY="exit error code from Backup of RAD file = %errorlevel%."
goto mailerror
)
exit
:mailerror
echo %BODY%
echo do something else..
```

As per [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan)'s comment. Some rare programs generate a negative errorlevel, if that is the case the first option will do, or this:

```
@echo off
if %errorlevel% GTR 1 if %errorlevel% lss 0 (
set BODY="exit error code from Backup of RAD file = %errorlevel%."
goto mailerror
)
exit
:mailerror
echo %BODY%
echo do something else..
```

Comment: Note: some (rare) programs do return negative errorlevels, so this *might* also need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Your question phrasing suggests you want to `Exit` if the errors are `0` or `1`:

```bat
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 0 IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 EXIT /B
REM MAILERROR CODE BELOW HERE
```